# WooCommerce custom pricing for businesses

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress website using WooCommerce and I want businesses to be able to contact me for pricing. Currently, I have 3 set packages, but I am looking to get rid of them and just use the contact for pricing.

My question is: is there a way to set custom pricing per business that contacts me?

I can't think of a way to do this just by using WooCommerce. I would ideally like to create their account and assign them a package, but even then I am not sure if that's possible.

If anyone has ever done this before please let me know how.

Comment: There is a dedicated WordPress stack exchange site where you might have more chances of getting answers

Comment: Yes this is possible. Look at the plugin Woo Discount Rules Pro. This will do what you want (I am not affiliated with the plugin, but am currently using it on a site and it does exactly what you are asking). Voting to close as off-topic.